AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute '_window_exists'. Did you mean: 'winfo_exists'
El siguiente codigo se llama desde el programa principal, se trata de una ventana Toplevel que necesita realizar tareas asincronas ( para efecto de lapregunta solo realiza un conteo progresivo pero necesito realizar 3 tareas más, todas asincronas). La clase hereda de CustomTkinter.CtkToplevel y de  AsyncCTk.
El codigo:
import asyncio
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
from async_tkinter_loop import async_handler
from async_tkinter_loop.mixins import AsyncCTk
import tkinter as tk



class App(customtkinter.CTkToplevel, AsyncCTk):  

  def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()
    self.geometry("800x500")
    self.i = 5

    self.contador = tk.Label(self,font=("montserrat", 17, "bold"), fg="red")
    self.contador.place(x=440,y=427)
    self.contador.lift()

    self.texto_contador = tk.Label(self,font=("montserrat", 15), fg="black", text="Tiempo restante:   Seg")
    self.texto_contador.place(x=260,y=430)
    self.texto_contador.lower()
    
    self.conteo()
    
    self.async_mainloop()

  @async_handler  
  async def conteo(self):
    
    print("contador")
    self.i = 0
    while self.i < 70:
        self.i += 1
        self.contador.config(text=str(self.i))
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)


 App()

estoy recibiendo el siguiente error al compilar (aquí dejo el Traceback)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\robert\Desktop\fuerzapp\forms\pruebas.py", line 40, in <module>
App()
File "c:\Users\robert\Desktop\fuerzapp\forms\pruebas.py", line 27, in __init__
self.async_mainloop()
File "C:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\async_tkinter_loop\mixins.py", line 16, in async_mainloop
if not self._window_exists:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute '_window_exists'. Did you mean: 
'winfo_exists'?

He intentado colocando

class App(customtkinter.CTk, AsyncCTk):

Y funciona a la perfección pero necesito que sea Toplevel ya que tengo la ventana del programa principal corriendo al mismo tiempo.
De su ayuda estaré muy agradecido

if name_== 'main': App()

@Bryro. Parece que tienes un underscore de más en "name___"

@CandidMoe si es que vi que le agegaga negrita e intente editarla pero luego vi que no se podia y lo deje porque se me paso el tiempo para editar xD

Parece que el editor de SO le jugó una mala pasada a Bryro. El debe haber escrito esto para iniciar la aplicación
if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()

pero como este sitio tiene un editor para los comentarios y otro para para las respuestas, lo que funciona en uno no funciona en el otro. En este caso, transformó/desparecio arbitrariamente los underscores.
Una de las muchas deficiencias de la UI de SO
